# Issue with counting in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I try to solve an issue but I need help :)

Actually this query works, I have the sum of all sales in the last colums:

```
SELECT DISTINCT epps.SKU, epc.name , 
                 COUNT(*) FROM ERP_CUSTOMER_ORDER eco
                INNER JOIN ERP_CUSTOMER_ORDER_ITEMS_2 ecoi2 ON ecoi2.ERP_CUSTOMER_ORDER_index = eco.`index`
                INNER JOIN ERP_PROD_PRODUCT_SIZES epps ON ecoi2.prod_index = epps.ID
                INNER JOIN ERP_PROD_CATALOG epc ON epps.`SKUf ID`= epc.`index`

                        WHERE (eco.state = "processing" OR eco.state= "complete")
                            AND eco.created_at > DATE_ADD("2015-11-06",INTERVAL 12 HOUR)
                            AND eco.created_at < DATE_ADD("2015-12-06",INTERVAL 12 HOUR)
                            AND epc.attribute_set = "Contact Lenses"
                            AND eco.order_location = "KL"

GROUP BY epps.SKU
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

[image: Result of this query]

I want the number of products sold per 30 days period. I also would like the number of products sold the last month. Yet it doesn't work. This is my new query:

I would like to compare the sales between 2 different months

```
SELECT DISTINCT epps.SKU, epc.name , 
                (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ERP_CUSTOMER_ORDER eco
                INNER JOIN ERP_CUSTOMER_ORDER_ITEMS_2 ecoi2 ON ecoi2.ERP_CUSTOMER_ORDER_index = eco.`index`
                INNER JOIN ERP_PROD_PRODUCT_SIZES epps ON ecoi2.prod_index = epps.ID
                INNER JOIN ERP_PROD_CATALOG epc ON epps.`SKUf ID`= epc.`index`

                        WHERE (eco.state = "processing" OR eco.state= "complete")
                            AND eco.created_at > DATE_ADD("2015-11-06",INTERVAL 12 HOUR)
                            AND eco.created_at < DATE_ADD("2015-12-06",INTERVAL 12 HOUR)
                            AND epc.attribute_set = "Contact Lenses"
                            AND eco.order_location = "KL"
                            ),


                            (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ERP_CUSTOMER_ORDER eco
                INNER JOIN ERP_CUSTOMER_ORDER_ITEMS_2 ecoi2 ON ecoi2.ERP_CUSTOMER_ORDER_index = eco.`index`
                INNER JOIN ERP_PROD_PRODUCT_SIZES epps ON ecoi2.prod_index = epps.ID
                INNER JOIN ERP_PROD_CATALOG epc ON epps.`SKUf ID`= epc.`index`

                        WHERE (eco.state = "processing" OR eco.state= "complete")
                            AND eco.created_at > DATE_ADD("2015-10-06",INTERVAL 12 HOUR)
                            AND eco.created_at < DATE_ADD("2015-11-06",INTERVAL 12 HOUR)
                            AND epc.attribute_set = "Contact Lenses"
                            AND eco.order_location = "KL"
                            )
FROM ERP_CUSTOMER_ORDER eco
                INNER JOIN ERP_CUSTOMER_ORDER_ITEMS_2 ecoi2 ON ecoi2.ERP_CUSTOMER_ORDER_index = eco.`index`
                INNER JOIN ERP_PROD_PRODUCT_SIZES epps ON ecoi2.prod_index = epps.ID
                INNER JOIN ERP_PROD_CATALOG epc ON epps.`SKUf ID`= epc.`index`                                          
GROUP BY epps.SKU 
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

[image: Result of this query]

I used roughly the same framework but I can't have the same result than before.

Thanks a lot!
Guillaume

Answer (score 0):

Is performance a major concern for you here? If not, using two subqueries and joining them would probably work quite well. Something like this (not tested):

```
SELECT * from
(
SELECT DISTINCT epps.SKU, epc.name , 
                 COUNT(*) FROM ERP_CUSTOMER_ORDER eco
                INNER JOIN ERP_CUSTOMER_ORDER_ITEMS_2 ecoi2 ON ecoi2.ERP_CUSTOMER_ORDER_index = eco.`index`
                INNER JOIN ERP_PROD_PRODUCT_SIZES epps ON ecoi2.prod_index = epps.ID
                INNER JOIN ERP_PROD_CATALOG epc ON epps.`SKUf ID`= epc.`index`

                        WHERE (eco.state = "processing" OR eco.state= "complete")
                            AND eco.created_at > DATE_ADD("2015-11-06",INTERVAL 12 HOUR)
                            AND eco.created_at < DATE_ADD("2015-12-06",INTERVAL 12 HOUR)
                            AND epc.attribute_set = "Contact Lenses"
                            AND eco.order_location = "KL"

GROUP BY epps.SKU
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
) a
inner join 
(
SELECT DISTINCT epps.SKU, epc.name , 
                 COUNT(*) FROM ERP_CUSTOMER_ORDER eco
                INNER JOIN ERP_CUSTOMER_ORDER_ITEMS_2 ecoi2 ON ecoi2.ERP_CUSTOMER_ORDER_index = eco.`index`
                INNER JOIN ERP_PROD_PRODUCT_SIZES epps ON ecoi2.prod_index = epps.ID
                INNER JOIN ERP_PROD_CATALOG epc ON epps.`SKUf ID`= epc.`index`

                        WHERE (eco.state = "processing" OR eco.state= "complete")
                            AND eco.created_at > DATE_ADD("2015-10-06",INTERVAL 12 HOUR)
                            AND eco.created_at < DATE_ADD("2015-11-06",INTERVAL 12 HOUR)
                            AND epc.attribute_set = "Contact Lenses"
                            AND eco.order_location = "KL"

GROUP BY epps.SKU
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
) b
on a.SKU = b.SKU and a.name = b.name
```

Note that this query will not work if your data doesn't have zero-values in it (eg for a month that didn't sell any lenses, if you have no rows, this query would return no results for either month because of the inner join).